# Excel: How do I efficiently condition a cell so that I can identify a cell with observation counts less than a certain number?

Tags: excel

[image]

Basically I wanted to only extract the top 2 rows for every Entry #, but if the Entry # does not have 2 rows it is not used.

I tried IF statements and eliminating blanks and whatnot, but if this is a large data I would not be able to handle it.

Comment: You could do this pretty easily with `Power Query` if that is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind adding a few columns, here's one method. Arrange how you wish.

Column's B and F are your original data.

Column C, in cell C2, input your first value manually (1 in this case).

Then here's the **formula for Cell C3**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),C2,B3)
```

**Cell D2 formula**:

```
=IF(C2=C1,D1+1,1)
```

**Cell E2 formula**:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C2)>1,"Yes","No")
```

Drag down your formulas.

[image]

Then you can filter on column E for YES, and filter on column D for 1 & 2.

[image]